# compiling a regex query with a row in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, regex-lookarounds

I have two csv files. I want to take each row in turn of csv1, find its entry in csv 2 and then pull out other information for that row from csv2.

I'm struggling with the items I am looking for are company names. In both csv1 and csv2 they may or may not have the suffix 'LTD, LTD, Limited or LIMITED' within the name so I would like the query to not include these substrings in the query. My code is still only finding exact matches, rather than ignoring 'Ltd' etc. I'm guessing it's the way I'm combining 'row[0]' with the regex query but can't figure it out.

**Code**

```
import re, csv

with open (r'c:\temp\noregcompanies.csv', 'rb') as q:
    readerM=csv.reader(q)
    for row in readerM:
        companySourcename = row[0]+"".join(r'.*(?!Ltd|Limited|LTD|LIMITED).*')   
        IBcompanies = re.compile(companySourcename)
        IBcompaniesString = str(companySourcename)

    with open (r'c:\temp\chdata.csv', 'rb') as f:
        readerS = csv.reader(f)
        for row in readerS:
            companyCHname = row[0]+"".join(r'.*(?!Ltd|Limited|LTD|LIMITED)*')
            CHcompanies = re.compile(companyCHname)
            if CHcompanies.match(IBcompaniesString):
                print ('Match is: ',row [0], row[1])
                with open (r'c:\temp\outputfile.csv', 'ab') as o:
                    writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',')
                    writer.writerow(row) t
```